# Explicitly setting `Content-Length` header in `java.net.http.HttpRequest`

Tags: httpclient, java-11, java-http-client

I want to upload a file from `InputStream` over HTTP, and for this, I am using the new `HttpClient` provided as part of `JDK11`. When I try to set the `Content-Length` while creating a post request I get an `IllegalArgumentException` saying `restricted header name: "Content-Length"` and if I try to upload a file from `InputStream` without the `Content-Length` header I get an `internal server error` from the server where I want to upload the file. Is there any option to set the `Content-Length` in the request in Java 11?
CodeI am using for creating `HttpRequest`:

```
var postRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                             .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofInputStream(() -> inputStream))
                             .uri(new URI(url))
                             .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, Long.toString(inputStreamSupplier.getFileSize()))
                             .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
                             .build();
```

**Note:** It won't be possible to update to Java 12 to allow the restricted headers.

I could also use another library, just wanted to know if there is an option to use the classes from JDK before switching to `RestTemplate` from Spring. (yes, it's deprecated, As the alternative uses spring boot can't use it at the moment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use [fromPublisher](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.html#fromPublisher(java.util.concurrent.Flow.Publisher,long)):

```
var bodyPublisher = BodyPublishers
    .fromPublisher(BodyPublishers.ofInputStream(()-> inputStream)), length);
```

Note that you must ensure that the InputStream delivers exactly `length` bytes.